# Can different power socket in one house charge at different speeds

Tags: power-supply, mains

We all have power socket at our homes. Now I observed something:

When I connect my phone for charging at socket it charges up at a faster rate than other socket obviously with the same cable and adaptor

How is this is possible since all the connections have a common connection to main circuit in the house?

This is the typical circuit . I think the purpose of switch is only to supply power and that will be available at equation rate but is it somehow possible that the circuit had some problem which gave me this observation?
[image]charges fast and less used

[image] charges slow and frequently used

Comment: Please [edit] your question to explain what you mean by "charging points". The phrase suggests a 5 V USB socket but your diagram suggest mains power sockets, not charging points. Then explain if you are using the same charger plugged in at each socket or different chargers.

Comment: @Transistor at the end of the circuit there are 3 diff switches which I comprehend as points

Comment: What is a "diff switch"? What is a "point"? Your edit is even more confusing. A **switch** is what you use to turn a light on and off. A **wall power socket** is for mains power for plug-in appliances such as food mixer, vacuum cleaner or phone charging power-supply. You don't plug things into a switch.

Comment: @Transistor Some wall power sockets have switches, too. In the UK it's more unusual to have *unswitched* sockets.

Comment: @SiHa, thanks. I'm aware of that as we use the British Standard 13A system here. I'm trying to get the OP to explain clearly what the situation is. For example, 13A sockets here and other standards in other countries now have USB power outlets built into the power sockets.

Comment: If you could add a photo of the phone, cable, charging point, switch, and electrical outlet for both the *fast* and *slow* locations, a concise answer can be given.

Comment: @rdtsc done though not a major difference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Highly unlikely that the charging points are centralized. Much more likely that each USB charging point is its own device, each with its own connection to the mains. If some are charging differently than others, it is the fault of the local USB charger.

The reason? Long lines have high voltage drop which is bad when your voltage is already low to begin with. Losing 1V when your voltage is 120V is barely noticeable. Losing 1V when your voltage is 5V is very bad.

Comment: Dont know where u from but in india this is the most common circuit in all housing a common circuit which further divides to different switches

Comment: I can't actually see your picture. It is too small and can't be made larger. What I can see seems to show 120V running everywhere and no low voltage line which, if true, means separate USB chargers.

Comment: https://images.app.goo.gl/oEDPJBRtbJkPHbW9A   take a look

Comment: Nowhere in that diagram is there a charging port. Only high voltage outlets. Describe what you mean by "charging point". To most people, a charging point means a USB plug that has 5VDC on it that you plug your phone directly into. All your diagrams show outlets which have >100VAC on them which needs to be regulated down to 5VDc first before your phone can use it, which matches what I described in my answer.

Comment: What I mean is every connection in a house where we plug in devices have a common potential drop so it is weird to have different rates of charging for same device when connected on differnt points

Comment: @Anusha That common potential is so much higher than what you need to charge your phone it doesn't matter when it gets regulated down. What you are thinking of is like thinking that someone upstream on the river has an easier time scooping out water with a bucket than someone downstream on the river. The river is so big compared to your bucket that it doesn't matter.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119191/discussion-between-anusha-and-dknguyen).

Answer (score 1):

The voltage on ac sockets on a house can very quite a bit. From the circuit breaker panel comes many different branch circuits. If there is a branch circuit supply a huge amount of cuurent to a portable heater, the voltage at the circuit breaker panel may be 120VAC but the voltage at the socket which connects heater is at 110VAC because 10 volts are dropped by the wiring.  But another socket in the house may be 120V because there is nothing hooked up to it, no current flow, no voltage drop.

But most phone chargers provide the same amount of power to a phone down to 90 volts at the socket, so this is not a problem. If you have an older adapter that is heavy because it has a big transformer in it (it also gets hot) to charge your phone....there could be a difference in time to charge

Answer (score -1):

5V USB chargers are not all built the same and vary in their intended output, from 500mA on older models or models specific to low power devices to 4 or more amp on multiport chargers.  Not all chargers can sustain 5V at maximum charging current.  They also regulate the 5V output voltage based on an internal reference, so reasonable line voltage changes won't affect the USB charger output.

In addition to that, USB chargers with additional charge voltage exist.  On my Samsung S6, it's called adaptive fast charge, but I believe the other voltages were built as options into the USB standard.  USB C can support up to 90W based on existing chargers.

Many or most phones will say "Charging" or "Fast charging depending on what you plug them into.

Answer (score -1):

Just measure voltage in your wall outlet (with some load plug in!), it should be the equal. If not the problem  is in house installation.